# PHP - Printing Issues

Tags: php, paragraph

I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm just trying to do some basics but when I run the following code, I get this: https://gyazo.com/94f0181159312764de2b4d8a304791ec

Code:

```
<?php

      $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "dbName");
      if (!$connection) {
        echo "<p>Error connecting to the Database.</p>";
      }
      else if ($connection) {
        echo "<p>Connected to the Database.</p>";
      }

?>
```

Also, I'm not asking about the connection error here, I'm asking about why it prints literal code. Thanks to anyone to answers!

Comment: You can just use `else` by the way

Comment: @AndyHolmes yeah i know but thats besides the point

Comment: You might need to install `libapache2-mod-php` for the corresponding PHP version if you are using Apache. If you are using nginx I think you should install `php-fpm`. Make sure you restart your server after installing the module. Also make sure you have correct apache or nginx configuration.

Comment: What's your file's extension? Is it PHP... if it's set to html, or txt, it will not run properly.

Comment: @Samuel yeah its a `.php` file

Comment: @APixelVisuals honestly, your code looks fine; I don't see anything wrong with it. Are you running this on your local machine? What's your local server, wamp, xampp?

Comment: @Samuel i literally just drag and dropped the .php file into chrome lmao but now ive found out i need to go to https://localhost but that just says that I cant reach it

Comment: Yes, you have to have your server running and then go to the localhost... what server are you using?

Comment: @Samuel thats what im trying to figure out how to do. Setting up a server on localhost. if you know any good tutorials or something a link would be appreciated :)

Comment: @APixelVisuals are you on Windows or Mac or Linux?

Comment: @Samuel Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: @Samuel hey I found a tutorial and got localhost to work and I can connect to the database and PHP works fine. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem man... @APixelVisuals keep coding!

Answer (score 0):

HI I'm also new in php but this code should work so far.

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "dbName");
if($conneciont->connect_error){ die("Connection error".connect_error);} else echo ("Successfull connected");
```

Comment: this question is asking about why the result is a printing of the code, not about the connection to the db

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so from the comments it seems that you do not have a local server installed. I recommend you use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html); it has a large community base, and there's usually a lot of info out there to help you troubleshoot.

To get started it's simple, download their installer for Windows from their [download page](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html). There you will have three options; PHP 5.6, 7.0, and 7.1; choose based on what PHP code you have... if you are new, I recommend going with the newest and best. PHP 7.1 has many great features, as well as bettering the OOP interface.

Installing is straightforward. Run through the installer and usually you can get aways with just installing the default settings, especially if you are new.

Once installed move your code to `C:\XAMPP\htdocs\`. Create a folder for each project; it's usually the best way to stay organized.

Once you moved your files, on your browser go to `http://localhost/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME`.

You can also setup databases and tables from your `PHPMyAdmin` (for xampp the url is `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`) which comes out of the box with XAMPP.